# Variable "WRITEDUMP" is undefined

Tags: coldfusion

OK, it's my first try with ColdFusion and I'm having some serious trouble.

I just tried

```
writeDump(someVar);
```

within a `<cfscript>` block, and it keeps throwing errors.

What's going on?

---

**P.S.** What I'm trying to do is something similar to php's `print_r` or `var_dump`; so if you know of a better/alternative way to achieve the very same thing, I'm all ears! :-)

Comment: show us the complete code you are running

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running as writeDump was only introduced in version 9? Outside of the <cfscript> try testing <cfdump var="#someVar#">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking [James's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983718/variable-writedump-is-undefined#comment35098928_22983718) forward, what is your CF version, because `writedump` will work only in version 9 & later. If you are on version 8 or earlier, you have to use `<cfdump var="#someVar#">`

If you have to use it in `cfscript`, then you can write your own custom function

```
<cffunction name="myDump" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="arg" required="true" type="any">
    <cfdump var="#Arguments.arg#">
</cffunction>
```

and then call this function inside `cfscript` block

```
mydump(somevar);
```

Comment: Recreating the function is really the wrong answer. _"If you are on version 8 or earlier..."_ - then ***upgrade!*** CF8 is an obsolete version lacking plenty of functionality (as the lack of writeDump demonstrates).

Comment: Deciding which version of ColdFusion to use is not always a decision made by a developer.

Comment: It is always a developer's decision whether to accept inferior tools. If the company refuses both to upgrade obsolete software and to provide suitable training for new developers, then the developer should be looking for a different company; one that doesn't invest in architecture or employees is not a sensible place to work.

Comment: so that mean if legacy application has an issue, just throw the whole application out? I agree, that upgrading is best bet, but there are many more variables involved. What if company is finding it short to hire developers (one of the biggest drawback with our technology in current times), may be that is the reason that they asked somebody else from different tech to get acquainted with CF?

Comment: A legacy application is arguably one that has _already_ been thrown out, (otherwise it wouldn't have become legacy). But my point is _the first part_ of any response to an issue involving a CF6/7/8 application must be a recommendation to upgrade, because _the software is obsolete_. This is especially true for a non-CF developer, because they're less likely to know that it isn't supported (and importantly what that means in terms of security). To simply say "here's a UDF" without first giving that information is doing the OP a disservice.

Comment: Fair enough. I already said, I agree on suggesting upgrade. But like Dan said, this is a decision most of time made by people who do looks in terms on $$$ rather than anything else. I will ensure that I suggest upgrade before I suggest work around in that particular version because OP may need a solution after all :)